# Taxonomy menu block order

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a Taxonomy Menu Block, displaying the whole tree of a taxonomy category.

However if I change the order of the taxonomy terms it does not affect the Taxonomy Menu Block. Does anyone know if it is possible to make the Taxonomy Menu Block sort the terms in the order they are sorted in the taxonomy tree..? An illustration of the problem:

My menu block is showing:

```
Item A
Item B
Item C
```

If i then go to the tree of taxonomy terms and move Item C above item B like this:

```
Item A
Item C
Item B
```

the Taxonomy Menu Block still shows:

```
Item A
Item B
Item C
```

Answer (score 0):

if this module does not respect the order, try to make a view and use its block. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806028/drupal-taxonomy-block-vocabulary-listing